# Multichain vs Quorum

Tags: quorum

Other than multichain is utxo based and quorum is account based, what are some major differences between multichain and quorum?

Scalability, consensus, turing complete language support, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best comparison would be between actual implementations vs concepts. But, essentially, a multichain implies that theres multiple databases/evms per communicating nodes (this depends on the implementation) with multiples of the states stored somewhere. Quorum is a single chain, meaning that the same network and database stores everything thats occurring between parties. Practically, in Quorum, this means that we use the same blockchain database for everything, tho we do separate public vs private state on things marked as private.